# i want to merge pdf in laravel trying by package lynX39 But can not complete install

Tags: laravel, pdfmerger

- Installing lynx39/lara-pdf-merger (dev-master e952590): Cloning e95259079c

In Git.php line 325:

Failed to clone https://github.com/deltaaskii/lara-pdf-merger.git via https
, ssh protocols, aborting.

- https://github.com/deltaaskii/lara-pdf-merger.git
  Cloning into '/home/mostafa/Web App/tmc/vendor/lynx39/lara-pdf-merger'...
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/deltaaskii/lara-pdf-merger.gi
  t/': Could not resolve host: github.com
- git@github.com:deltaaskii/lara-pdf-merger.git
  Cloning into '/home/mostafa/Web App/tmc/vendor/lynx39/lara-pdf-merger'...
  ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I Got Solution By Using anther
https://github.com/jurosh/php-pdf-merge
Package that not depend on Lynx39

"jurosh/pdf-merge": "^2.0"

```
$pdf = new \Jurosh\PDFMerge\PDFMerger;

// add as many pdfs as you want
$pdf->addPDF('path/to/source/file.pdf', 'all', 'vertical')
  ->addPDF('path/to/source/file1.pdf', 'all')
  ->addPDF('path/to/source/file2.pdf', 'all', 'horizontal');

// call merge, output format `file`
$pdf->merge('file', 'path/to/export/dir/file.pdf');
```

Tested and Worked Well ....

Comment: I have tried this package but still I can't locate s3 file

Comment: How did you load s3 file url

Comment: i didn't try them .

Comment: Thank you but I was able to download it from s3 then I converted downloaded version to PDF 1.4 using ghostscript then I used Jurosh Package to merge all pdf's together.